# Apps script google sheets

Tags: iphone, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a working script on my Google Sheet, That adds dates to the Google calendar every time I add a new row in my task-to-do sheet via the installable triggers (I have 2 triggers: On change and On edit).
But when I add a new row to the sheet on my iPhone, the calendar doesn't get updated with the new date.

I searched and tried many solutions, can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Logs? Execution transcripts? Breakpoints?

Comment: I just added an onChange() installable trigger to my spreadsheet and I can cause a trigger to fire with my iPhone.  Check your executions to make sure you're not getting errors.

Comment: Hi there Majd Rezik! In addition to what TheMaster and Cooper commented above, could you please share the script?